# Probability $A$ wins given $A$ has $6$ points and $B$ has $4$ points (coin flipping)

Tags: probability

A has $6$ points and B has $4$ points. They flip a coin and if it's a head, then $A$ gets a point from $B$. If it's a tail, then $B$ gets a point from $A$. What's the probability that $A$ wins with $10$ points?

One way to do this is with a Markov chain. However, that quickly gets like a tedious solution. What's the intuitive way to answer this?

If we get a tails, then $A$ and $B$ will both have $5$ points, so the probability that $A$ wins is $\frac 1 2$. How do we use this information?

Comment: Why does the problem have they players have 6 and 4 points and play until 10 rather than 2 and 0 points and play until 6?  Or why not 169458459 and 169458457 and play until 16945863?

Comment: Please try editing your question, adding more context, your own thoughts and what you've tried, etc. Reading [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w_n$ be the probability that $A$ wins by starting with $n$ points. Clearly $w_5=\frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry and $w_{10}=1$.
Also
$$w_6=\frac{1}{2}(w_5+w_7),\; w_7=\frac{1}{2}(w_6+w_8),\;w_8=\frac{1}{2}(w_7+w_9),\;w_9=\frac{1}{2}(w_8+w_{10}).$$
This gives that $w_n-2w_{n+1}+w_{n+2}=(w_n-w_{n+1})-(w_{n+1}-w_{n+2})=0$ for any $n\in[5,8]$, *hence $w_n$ is linear over $[5,10]$*. By interpolation it follows that $w_n = w_5+\frac{n-5}{10}$ and $w_6=\color{red}{60\%}$.

Comment: How did $W_n=\frac{1}{2}W_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}W_{n+1}$ become $W_n - 2W_{n+1} + W_{n+2}$ ?

Comment: @Marco: it is just a $n\to n+1$ shift. Both identities tell us that each term is the average between the previous one and the next one.

Comment: Could I also ask you for clarification on how you got to the final equation : $w_n=w_5+\frac{n−5}{10}$ ?

Comment: @Marco: I wrote that: $w_{n+1}-w_{n}$ is constant hence $w_n=An+B$. We know $w_5$ and $w_{10}$, so we know everything in the middle.

Comment: Can you confirm that the formula for interpolation is $\frac{w_{10} - w_5}{w_6-w_5}=\frac{1-0.5}{x-0.5}$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{10-5}{6-5}=\frac{0.5}{x-0.5}$ $\rightarrow$ $x=\frac{3}{5}$ ?